# CSS vertical timeline with custom dotted line on specific div

Tags: css

I have a CSS timeline and I wanted to have a dotted line only on a specific div container not the entire timeline to be dotted. I also wanted to change the color so its dotted with a different color from the rest of the timeline.

I have tried adding a custom class .marginTop but it doesnt change the color for the specific part of the timeline I want to change

Similar to the image below

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="timelinex" >

  <div class="containerx leftx marginTop">
    <div class="contentx">

      <p><img src="assets/img/1.jpg" style="border-radius: 0.5em;border-top-left-radius: 120px; border-bottom-right-radius: 120px"></p>
        <h5 style="color:#999;font-style: 0.5em"> DAY 1 </h5>
        <div> Mind Booster</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**SCSS**

```
* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */
.timelinex {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 5em;
}

/* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */


.timelinex::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 4px;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.timelinex.non_complete::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 4px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  border:1em dotted #f4f4f4;
}

.timelinex.marginTop::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-top: -23px;
}


/* Container around content */
.containerx {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 50%;
}

/* The circles on the timeline */
.containerx::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  right: -5px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.containerx.not_complete::after {
    background-color: #333 !important;
}


/* Place the container to the left */
.leftx {
  left: 0;
}

/* Place the container to the right */
.rightx {
  left: 50%;
}


/* Fix the circle for containers on the right side */
.rightx::after {
  left: -7px;
}

/* The actual content */
.contentx {
  padding: 2px 3px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: could you perhaps illustrate what the end result should be? I for one do not get it

Comment: ...also create a working jsfiddle of what you currently have.

Comment: Just uploaded an image

Comment: Change `background-color` to `border-color` in your `.timelinex.marginTop::after` styles.